# How to compare Map for common keys and print the output?

Tags: go

I have the following code which generates the following output

code:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type EntetiesClass struct {
    Name  string
    Value int32
}

// In the template, we use rangeStruct to turn our struct values
// into a slice we can iterate over
var htmlTemplate = `{{range $index, $element := .}}
{{range $element}}{{.Name}}={{.Value}}
{{- end}}
{{- end}}`

func main() {
    data := map[string][]EntetiesClass{
            "Container1": {{"Test", 15}},
            "Container2": {{"Test", 15}},
    }

    t := template.New("t")
    t, err := t.Parse(htmlTemplate)
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

}
```

link: https://play.golang.org/p/yM9_wWmyLY
Output:

Test=15
Test=15

I want to compare the Container1 with Container2 and if they have common key, i just want to print output only once.

Output:
Test=15

How can i achieve this? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: nit-pick: The spelling is "Entities", and Go doesn't have classes, so that term should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Dedup your data before passing to the template execution

   This means you can pre-process the data before passing to `t.Execute` to eliminate duplicates. You can do this using something like:

   ```
   m := map[EntitiesClass]bool{}
   for _, ... {
       m[ec] = true
       // Or maybe you want to aggregate "Container 1"
       // and "Container 2" in some way
   }
   ```

   Then you can just pass the processed data and the template itself remains virtually unchanged
2. Add a [custom function for your template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs)

   This means you can add a normal go function that receives as many `EntitiesClass` as you like and returns them deduplicated (perhaps with the mechanism from option 1).

   You can even do something like:

   ```
   {{if not customHaveSeenThisValueBefore }}
      ...
   {{ endif }}
   ```

For your simple example I would choose option 1, it seems easiest to leave templates very simple.

Comment: A fun go trick is to use a `map[EntitiesClass]struct{}` because you never need to actually look at the `bool`. This saves the memory that would be used by the `bool` because using an empty `struct{}` value doesn't allocate any. https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct

Comment: @RayfenWindspear That's a nice one to use when the map is large. But otherwise for small maps using bool makes for a nicer syntax when checking presence in the map. `if m[x]` vs `if _, ok := m[x]; ok`

Answer (score 0):

This applies some filtering logic. I'm using `text/template` because this code isn't using a server. It will work the same with `html/template`. When appending to slices of structs pointers have to be used. If you don't know why see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042439/go-append-to-slice-in-struct). `func isInSlice() bool` needs to be modded to your needs. This serves as an example.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Entitie struct {
    Results []*Data
}

type Data struct {
    Name  string
    Value int32
}

// Change this function to mod how to filter
func (e *Entitie) isInSlice(name string) bool {
    for _, item := range e.Results {
        if item.Name == name {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (e *Entitie) AddData(name string, value int32) {
    if !e.isInSlice(name) {
        e.Results = append(e.Results, &Data{Name: name, Value: value})
    }
}

// In the template, we use rangeStruct to turn our struct values
// into a slice we can iterate over
var template = `
    {{range $i, $e := .Data.Results}}
        {{$e.Name}} = {{$e.Value}}
    {{end}}
    `

func main() {
    data := make(map[string]Entitie)

    var entities Entitie

    entities.AddData("test", 15)
    entities.AddData("test", 15)
    entities.AddData("test2", 15)

    t := template.New("t")
    t, err := t.Parse(template)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    data["Data"] = entities

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```