# updating a nested struct slice with a function

Tags: go, struct, slice

With the respect to the following question:

[Go - append to slice in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042439/go-append-to-slice-in-struct)

I would like to propose a more complex case. It is the case of nested struct containing slices. Passing this slice of struct to a function I am not able to get it updated.
The example is here:

https://go.dev/play/p/W3JQfruFOmk

I am not sure if I can paste the code here because it is many lines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyBoxItem struct {
    Name string
}

type MyBox struct {
    BoxName string
    Items   []MyBoxItem
}

type MyBoxes []MyBox

func (box *MyBoxes) AddItem(items []MyBoxItem, boxName string) {
    for _, b := range *box {
        fmt.Println("Processing: ", b.BoxName)
        if b.BoxName == boxName {
            for _, item := range items {
                fmt.Println("Processing item: ", item.Name)
                b.Items = append(b.Items, item)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    item1 := MyBoxItem{Name: "Test Item 1"}
    item2 := MyBoxItem{Name: "Test Item 2"}
    item3 := MyBoxItem{Name: "Test Item 3"}
    item4 := MyBoxItem{Name: "Test Item 4"}

    boxItems1 := []MyBoxItem{}
    box1 := MyBox{BoxName: "firstBox", Items: boxItems1}
    boxItems2 := []MyBoxItem{}
    box2 := MyBox{BoxName: "secondBox", Items: boxItems2}

    boxSet := MyBoxes{}
    boxSet = append(boxSet, box1)
    boxSet = append(boxSet, box2)

    fmt.Println(boxSet)

    boxItems1 = append(boxItems1, item1)
    boxItems1 = append(boxItems1, item2)
    boxItems2 = append(boxItems2, item3)
    boxItems2 = append(boxItems2, item4)
    boxSet.AddItem(boxItems1, "firstBox")
    boxSet.AddItem(boxItems2, "secondBox")

    fmt.Println(boxSet)

}
```

Yes I can, the following is the output I am getting:

```
[{firstBox []} {secondBox []}]
Processing:  firstBox
Processing item:  Test Item 1
Processing item:  Test Item 2
Processing:  secondBox
Processing:  firstBox
Processing:  secondBox
Processing item:  Test Item 3
Processing item:  Test Item 4
[{firstBox []} {secondBox []}]
```

So, there is no update.

Comment: `[]MyBox` is a slice of `MyBox` values, and assignment is always a copy of a value. You either need to use pointers, or assign the updated value back to the slice.

Comment: DON'T down-vote you may b pro but here newcomers can learn

Comment: Nice read on this topic: https://medium.com/@xcoulon/3-ways-to-update-elements-in-a-slice-d5df54c9b2f8

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for _, b := range *box {
```

`b` is a copy of an element in `*box`, not the element itself. Use:

```
for i, b := range *box {
 ...
    (*box)[i].Items = append((*box)[i].Items, item)
```